# how to build a expression with a lot of variables having the same name pattern?

Tags: php, variables, design-patterns, let

i have 50 variables in my system script.
All have the same kind of naming like :

```
$case_un
$case_deux
$case_trois
...
$case_fourthy
```

I need to build a expression with all of them without writing the code of 50 variables names !

As all my variables'name begin by the pattern 'case_', is there a syntaxe to make the SUM of them  or another expression ?

i need to perform such thing :

```
   $test_of_cases = $case_un && $case_deux && $case_trois && ...........$case_fourthy ;
```

and also that thing :

```
  $total_of_sums = $sum_un + $sum_deux + ............$sum_fifthy ;
```

so, is there a way to code that in PHP ?
In formal language, i just need to SUM all the variables which name begins by 'case_' .

My 50 variables are not storable in a array because there are from differents sources & expression result.

I'm not sure, but i thing there is a kind of expression to perform that in other language :

```
    LET a=SUM (`*case_*`)
    LET b=XOR (`*case_*`)
    LET c=AND (`*case_*`)
```

i learnt that in my old studies 30years ago.....

i hope PHP can do the same, else not, i have to write 50 lignes of code !

Best regards

Comment: The causal relationship (are not storable in a array because...) doesn't seem to make sense, you can still add them into an array at any time. You can also make something similar (e.g. [Traversable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php))

Comment: of course i can add them manually in a array but it is the same problem : i have to write-code one by one , so if i have 50 variables, i need to push them 50 times, 50 line of codes . there is not syntaxe to push them in a array in one operation.  how tu push all my $cases_ variables into an array ?

Comment: I just don't understand why they are not storable in an array, can you show how these variables are set?

Comment: If they are globals, you can loop through the `$GLOBALS` array and find keys' name started with "case_", but this is not efficient.

Comment: my natural language is french, not english, i will try to simply an example :

Comment: i will try to simply an example: my variables are :  people_physic_eyes, people_physic_weight, people_physic_size, people_data_name, people_data_forname ,people_data_age  . i need to compare if one of the physical variable have change. i have 50 physical variable in the same table/array where there is also 50 other variables of not-physical data (name, forname,age).  all the variable are already in the same env (a array or a table or a list), but i can't separate them !   i need a syntaxe to gather only variable with the same name-pattern to do that ! so, i don't know if PHP can do that.

Comment: obviously it must be array $case. $case['un'] etc

Comment: $people['physic']['eyes'], $people['physic']['weight'], $people['physic']['size'], $people['data']['name'], $people['data']['forname'] ,$people['data']['age'] - WHAT's so complex with using this primitive approach which PHP is PERFECTLY capable for?

Comment: $total_of_sums = array_sum($sum);

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have a such array

```
$arr = [
    'people_physic_eyes' => 1,
    'people_physic_weight' => 2,
    ...
    'name' => 'james',
    'age' => 15,
    ...
];
```

You want to sum all the values whose key names start with "people_physic_", there are many ways to achieve this, here is one example by using [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$sum = array_reduce(
    array_keys($arr),
    function ($sum, $key) use ($arr) {
        # if the key starts with 'people_physic_', sum up the value
        return strpos($key, 'people_physic_') === 0 ? $sum + $arr[$key] : $sum;
    },
    0
);
```

But this is not efficient because you have to compare all the keys on each call.

Comment: Consider structuring your array properly as opposed to using clumsy naming patterns

Comment: These names are copied from the OP's last comment, and he said he can't separate them.